# Centos 7 minimal install can't talk to internet

Tags: network-programming, centos7

Newbie trying to install/set up `Centos 7`. Can ping other machines in the domain, but can't ping gateway, google.com etc. Gets `destination host unreachable` for `gateway` and `unknown host google.com` when pinging google.com

Please advice.

`etc/sysconfig/network-scripts:`

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=enp4s0
iUUID=c39e3407-a566-4586-8fb9-fd4e3bfc4617
DEVICE=enp4s0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR="192.168.192.150"
GATEWAY="208.67.254.41"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
DNS2="8.8.4.4"
```

`etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

`etc/sysconfig/network`

```
# Created by anaconda
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=centos7
GATEWAY=208.67.254.41
```

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general OS/networking tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it says unknown host google.com the machine is not able to route request to internet DNS server(8.8.8.8) to resolve google ip and when you ping the gateway it  destination host not reachable

For a machine to connect to other machine their the machine should be within lan if not on lan then there should be a machine which acts a gateway machine within lan in your case you have pointed gateway to 208.67.254.41 obviously it is not on lan so this machine 208.67.254.41 should be accessible from some machine in lan to do so use route command
which add a  routing entry in machines routing table

route add -host  gw  dev

In your case command goes like

route add -host 208.67.254.41 gw  dev

eg : route add -host 192.168.12.45 gw 192.168.12.1 dev eth0

Comment entries if ipv6 is not used

Make sure to keep ip forwarding on in the gateway machine in /etc/sysclt.conf on gateway machine

Comment: @K patel  - Centos box is within the LAN and hence I could ping other machines within the network. As you pointed out, I was using the ISP provided gateway, once I updated my `ifcfg-enp4s0` under network-scripts with my router ip address (192.168.192.1), it resolved the issue. Didn't had to modify the routing table. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled Network Manager?

Command line:

```
service NetworkManager status
```

Comment: Not that I am aware of. How do I check the status?